# Google Play Private Channel - can´t see it on my android device

Tags: android, private, smartphone, channel

I have published an android app with the Developer Console in the Google Play Private Channel. (Setting: "Make this app only to users in the Google apps domain, I have enabled in the console). On the device I logged in the play store with an account, which is in the domain, but I can not see the Private Channel!

Can someone help me please?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?